# Highlight Active Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm working on a website that has a side navigation on about 20 pages. Instead of copying and pasting the side navigation on each individual page, I created all of the links in a JS file and just added it to the HTML pages for easier ability to change if and when needed.

My question is: is there a way to have the active page [highlight on the side navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5tcZ.png)? This is my JS code (W3CSS is being used on the pages):

```
document.write('<h4>Services:</h4>\
<div class="w3-bar-block w3-light-grey">\
    <a href="/page/7/alternative-dispute-resolution" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Alternative Dispute Resolution</a>\
    <a href="/page/8/appellate-practice" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Appellate Practice</a>\
    <a href="/page/9/aviation-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Aviation Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/10/business-and-commercial-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Business and Commercial Law and Litigation</a>\
    <a href="/page/11/contract-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contract Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/12/construction-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Construction Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/13/design-professsional-representation" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Design Professional Representation</a>\
    <a href="/page/14/dram-shop-and-liquor-license" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Dram Shop and Liquor Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/15/employment-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Employment Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/17/enviromental-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Environmental Law, Abestos, and Toxic Torts</a>\
    <a href="/page/18/general-civil-litigation" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">General Civil Litigation</a>\
    <a href="/page/19/mass-transit-liability" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Government and Mass Transit Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/20/insurance-and-indemnity-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Insurance Coverage and Indemnity Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/21/ip-and-trademark-litigation" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Intellectual Property and Trademark Litigation</a>\
    <a href="/page/22/motor-vehical-law" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Motor Vehical Law</a>\
    <a href="/page/23/premises-liability" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Premises Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/24/product-liability" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Product Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/25/professional-liability" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Professional Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/26/transportation-liability" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Transportation, Trucking, and Highway Liability</a>\
    <a href="/page/27/workmens-compensation" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Workmens Compensation</a>\
</div>')
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-white" id="home" style="min-width:100%;">
        <div class="w3-content w3-white">
            <div class="w3-row">
                <div class="w3-twothird w3-margin-top" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: justify; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;">
                    <p>content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third w3-padding">
<script src="services.js"></script>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a class added to the current active page? Need to get an active class on the link itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - using a synchronous javascript file for maintaining navigation is generally a bad idea. If a user visits your site with JavaScript disabled, they would never see the navigation. A better option would be to pull in a shared navigation template with PHP or some other server-side language.

If you *really* need to do it client-side in this manner, your best bet would be to check each link in the navigation to see if it matches `location.pathname` and toggle a class if it is.

```js
// collect all navigation links with a query:
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.w3-bar-block.w3-light-grey a.w3-bar-item.w3-button');

// loop through the nav links: 
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    var link = navLinks[i];
    // check if link path equals current path and add a class
    if (link.pathname === location.pathname) {
        link.classList.add('w3-green');
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should really make the entire navigation dynamic. Here's an example:

```js
(function() {
    // store your list of sidebar links as an array of objects:
    var links = [
        {
            url: '/page/7/alternative-dispute-resolution',
            title: 'Alternative Dispute Resolution'
        },
        {
            url: '/page/8/appellate-practice',
            title: 'Appellate Practice'
        },
        {
            url: '/page/9/aviation-law',
            title: 'Aviation Law'
        }
    ];

    // start building your HTML:
    var html = '\
    <h4>Services:</h4>\
    <div class="w3-bar-block w3-light-grey">\
    ';

    // loop through all links and build their HTML:
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        // initial classes for each link:
        var classes = [
            'w3-bar-item',
            'w3-button'
        ];

        // check if this link is active and add a class
        if (link.url === location.pathname) {
            classes.push('w3-green');
        }

        // append HTML for each link:
        html += '<a href="' +
                link.url +
                '" class="' +
                classes.join(' ') +
                '" title="' +
                link.title +
                '">' +
                link.title +
                '</a>';
    });

    // add last bit of HTML:
    html += '</div>';

    // write it to the page:
    document.write(html);
})();
```

Comment: Some feedback to go with my downvote would be nice... :)

Comment: I got the first part to work just fine. Are you able to walk me through with the dynamic code? I can't seem to get it to work and JS isn't my strong point by no means. I also have a server that I'm working on, so PHP wouldn't be out of the question.

Thank you so much for your assistance :)

Comment: @xxdash it seems there was a syntax error in the array definition (missing comma - whoops). let me know if it still gives you trouble or if you have any specific questions about the implementation.

Comment: that worked PERFECTLY. Thank you SO MUCH for your assistance!